# How to configure kafka deserializer so that it let pass only keys with values?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a kafka consumer which does the deserialization of JSON.

I get big messages like :

```
{
   data1: [],
   data2: ["content"],
   data3: null,
   data4: [],
   data5: "foo",
   data6: "",
   data7: [""],
   data8: [null],
   ...
   dataX: []
}
```

with a lot of keys, where the values are null respective empty lists. I want handle only the keys, which does have values or lists with senseful content like *data2* or *data5* and ignore the others. Even with *data6* (empty string) and *data7* (list with empty string) I want stay.  This shall pass.

I have this kafka consumer configuration.

```
    private void configureAndInitConsumer() {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommit);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
   }
```

I see, that here the *org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer* is configured. But the config is for kafka consumer.

I can configure the deserializer by replacing the KafkaConsumer constructor.

```
JsonDeserializer<JsonNode> valueDeserializer = createCustomizedJsonDeserializer();
consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), valueDeserializer);
```

and then I add the method

```
private JsonDeserializer<JsonNode> createCustomizedJsonDeserializer() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, false);
        return new JsonDeserializer<>(JsonNode.class, objectMapper);
    }
```

The hint for this I got from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/915

Is is possible that the Deserializer ignores the keys without values? (empty lists or null values)

I realized that the Deserializer intern has an object mapper.
So I testest this:

```
public class ObjectMapperTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        System.exit(new ObjectMapperTest().start());

    }

    private int start() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String testJson = "{\"date1\":[],\"date2\":null,\"date3\":[null],\"date4\":[\"\"],\"date5\":[],\"date6\":\"\",\"date8\":\"foobar\"}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

        JsonNode jn = objectMapper.readTree(testJson);

        System.out.println(jn);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I get this result:

```
{"date1":[],"date2":null,"date3":[null],"date4":[""],"date5":[],"date6":"","date8":"foobar"}
```

- I see there, that date2 is still there.

Comment: You don't need a custom deserializer. You can use the StringDeserializer along with the ObjectMapper, which has an ignore null configuration, I think... That being said, Kafka is an implementation detail, and you should refer the Jackson documentation. Btw, the only key "without a value" is data3

Comment: You are right. The only key wiothout a value is data3. But I want also ignore empty Arrays.
I made some tests with objectMapper. 
Even the objectmapper I can't configure so that it ignores keys without values. The null configuration only works for serialization. Sadly not for deserialization.

Comment: Have you tried storing into a Hashmap/Treemap instead of JsonNode? Or will that fail since can't add null values into some maps?

Comment: final HashMap<String, List<Object>> map = objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonDocNode, HashMap.class);

This was my origin. This made the initial error: He maps keys with null and empty strings to the same. I need to differentiate between null and empty string (""). I asked therefore this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639381/jackson-objectmapper-treetovalue-maps-empty-string-to-null-instead-of-empty-string

What do you mean in your former comment with "ignore null configuration". Maybe we mean different things.

Comment: Not all your values are lists. You'd only be able to use `<String, Object>`. Null and empty string **are** different

Comment: Right. Before there was only lists accepted. This was working. I added now the possibility also to accept leafs only with my node traverse solution. Yes, my example coveres more. But even we I look only to the arrays I had the issue.

Comment: Maybe I am only thinking of `Include.NON_NULL` serializer features. AFAIK, deserializer needs to read every field, then can ignore certain ones when converting to a POJO, but not a generic container like a map or JsonNode/Object/Tree

Comment: @OneCricketeer: You are right. My issue was the value type inside HashMap. Changing to ```final HashMap<String, Object> map = objectMapper.treeToValue(jn, HashMap.class);``` at least lets ```treeValue``` work as expected.